# Calling a lib function and another function on single onpress in react native

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native app where i'm using `react-native share`. Here I am taking a screenshot of a component and I want to share the screenshot on any of the social platform. But I want to take the screenshot and share that on one button onpress which i'm not being able to do. Here's the code I have now:

```js
import {RNViewShot,captureScreen}  from "react-native-view-shot"
import Share, {ShareSheet} from 'react-native-share'

class First extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      visible: false,
      uri:''
    }
  }
    screenshot = () => {
      captureScreen({
        format: "jpg",
        quality: 0.8
      }) 
      .then(
        uri => this.setState({ uri: uri }),
        error => console.error("Oops, snapshot failed", error)
      );
    }
  
  onCancel() {
    console.log("CANCEL")
    this.setState({visible:false});
  }
  onOpen() {
    console.log("OPEN")
    this.setState({visible:true});
  }

  render() {
    let shareOptions = {
      title: "React Native",
      message: "Hola shareOptions",
      url: "uri",
      subject: "Share Link" //  for email
    };

    let shareImageBase64 = {
      title: "React Native",
      message: "This is from VIP live 4D",
      url: this.state.uri,
      subject: "Share Link" //  for email
    };
    
    return (
        <View>
           <Button
              onPress={() => Share.open(shareImageBase64) } >
              <Text>Share </Text>
           </Button>
          </View>
         
    );
  }
}

export default withNavigation(First)
```

Is there any way to call the screenshot function on the button onpress with the lib function it already has?

Comment: why don't you put `Share.open(shareImageBase64)` inside your `screenshot` method?

Comment: it doesn't work because (shareImageBase64) is in render method. Can you show me how are you suggesting to do so? @azium

Comment: pass it as an argument to your function

Comment: tried it like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sammet-joez5  ...but still no luck @azium

Comment: I have modified it a bit. Now when I click for the first time it can share only text no image. On the second press it shows image properly. Can you tell me whats going on..Here's the updated one: https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sammet-joez5

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (modified from your code):

```
screenshot=()=> {
   captureScreen({
     format: "jpg",
     quality: 0.8
   }).then(uri => {
     this.setState(()=>{
       return { uri: uri };
     ), ()=>{
       const shareImageBase64 = {
         title  : "React Native",
         message: "This is from VIP live 4D",
         url    : this.state.uri,
         subject: "Share Link" //  for email
       };
       Share.open(shareImageBase64);
     };         
   );       
 };
```

From what I can tell, the issue was that the Share.open was given the "this.state.uri" value before it was set. By taking the value from "this.state" in the setState callback, we can be sure that the value have been set at this point.